# Fit table cell width to be the same as asp image width

Tags: html, css, asp.net, html-table, webforms

I have below asp image in a table cell:

```
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Image runat="server" Width="64px" Height="64px" ImageUrl="~/Images/user64.png" />               
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="employee-group">                    
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblEmployeeFullname" Text="Claude" ></asp:Label>
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblIdEmployee" Text="34343d-dfadfsf-3433"></asp:Label>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

[image]
I am trying to adjust table cell width to be the same as image width. How can I do this?

Comment: If you know the image dimensions, would CSS be sufficient?

Comment: Use `<td width="1">`.

Answer (score 1):

Create a style with this setting.

table { table-layout: fixed; }
td { width: 50%; }